# Text selection in pgAdmin (Windows 7) not working

Tags: windows-7, pgadmin-4

When I want to run a certain line of code, pgAdmin will not let me highlight it. I can only highlight two characters at at time. I am using PostgreSQL 10 on windows 7 and it opens up in windows 7, can anyone help me?

For now I can only use shift to highlight stuff, it will not let me use the cursor.

[image]

Comment: Can you please pin the snapshots

Comment: I don't believe Internet-explorer has any way to natively display data from PostgreSQL, without some intervening tool.  You should tag whatever tool that is, as that is where the problem probably lies.  PostgreSQL itself is not a text editor.  It can neither allow nor prevent you from highlighting whatever you want.  It has no idea what is going on on your screen.

Comment: I am using pgAdmin, it works on my home computer when I use internet explorer but not on my work computer.